# How to access Redshift from a Lambda from a VPC in a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I have read most of the Stackoverflow questions and heaps of docs on the internet but for some reason can't get lambda to connect to Redshift when Redshift is in a different VPC and different AWS account.

I have two subnets associated with the VPC and an internet gateway and NAT gateway are attached to the VPC. This is the VPC that the Lambda function is associated with. I added the NAT elastic ip to the security group of Redshift security group. The NAT is in the route table pointing to Redshift Elastic ip.

I following methods do work:

- taking lambda out of the VPC and opening Redshift to public (0.0.0.0) which is not ideal
- closing Redshift to the public and making the query from an EC2 instance in the VPC where the Lambda function is (put EC2 ip in Redshift security group)

Any idea how to get lambda to use the elastic ip of the NAT or something along those lines? Does the NAT in the route table need to point to elastic ip of Redshift or to a CIDR block or something similar? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As you said opening your Redshift to internet is really not the best answer, you should really consider using it only in an internet way.

So you will find below what I recommend to you:
- Bind you Lambda VPC to Redshift VPC using a VPC Peering (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html). Be careful to follow all steps for route table.
- Once your VPC peering has been made, you will be able to declare directly you Lambda Security Group to your Redshift Security group to allow inbound access.

You will then be able to remove the internet-facing of your Redshift Cluster and only use it with an internal way.

Then if you still want to use your way be careful of:
- Be careful to deploy your Lambda into your private subnets (to be able to use NAT Gateway EIP) and be sure to have all your routes configured (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html). If you deploy your lambda into your pubic subnets, it's gonna be harder to configure your Redshift Security group.
- Then allow your Lambda VPC EIP to Redshift security group (inbound rule)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to add Lambda Security Group to Redshift Security group and see if that works too. I assume it would as long as you have a NAT pointing to 0.0.0.0 in one of the subnets of the lambda VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the following gist: https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7

Essentially, what I was doing wrong was using one route table. I also was pointing the NAT to the elastic ip of Redshift.

All I had to do was delete the NAT from the original route table and create a new additional route table. I then add the NAT into the new route table and associate that route table with the other subnet that is in the VPC. I point the NAT to 0.0.0.0 instead of the Redshift elastic ip.

This allowed me to get rid of the "open to public" issue in the Redshift security group. I also believe the NAT helps the Lambda stay secure from public connections but would need clarification on that.